# How to post from AngularJS to SpringMVC

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

I have one post method in angularJS and I send post method to Spring MVC but Spring MVC doesn't return new ModelAndView.

- **AngularJS**
  **

  ```
  var app = angular.module('userApp', []);

  app.controller('userController', [ "$scope", "$http",

      function($scope, $http) {

          $scope.user = {};

          $scope.addUser = function() {
              var response = $http.post('resultA', $scope.user)
              response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  $scope.message = data;
              });
              response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  alert("failure message: ");
              });
              alert("aa");
              $scope.name = '';
              $scope.employees = '';
              $scope.headoffice = '';
          };

      } ]);
  ```
- **SPRING MVC**

  ```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/resultA", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody ModelAndView submitFormA(@RequestBody User user) {

      System.out.println(user.getUsername()+"");      
      return new ModelAndView("resultA");
  }
  ```

Comment: Do you get any error? Does the `username` message get print out in the console?

Comment: yes username message  print out in the  console.

Comment: Do you have any view with name `resultA`? If you want return `returnA` string, change method return type to `String`.

Comment: My jsp file name is resultA.jsp.Return type String doesn't work.

Comment: Can you enable debug log and post result here?

Comment: i cant debug log,Are you share example?

Answer (score 0):

Your code look fine. Please make sure that `resultA` view exist. Or if you want to return an String, change method return type to `String`.

Comment: My jsp file name is resultA.jsp.Return type String doesn't work.